# Ça aura pris du temps

Tags: grammaire, temps-grammatical

I'm having great difficulty in understanding the reason why future tense must be used although the meanings indicate the past.

- "Ça aura pris du temps, mais"

It took some time but I now realize how great my father was.

Why can't you say "Ça a pris du temps, mais"? What's the difference?

Answer (score 2):

D'abord "*aura pris*" n'est pas exactement un futur puisque c'est : un futur **antérieur**. (participe passé du verbe prendre précédé par l'auxilaire avoir conjugué au futur)

En soi, le futur antérieur n'indique pas nécessairement une action dans le futur mais bien plutôt une action **antérieure** à celle coordonnée (je réalise que mon père était un grand homme).
Cette action antérieure peut donc fort bien se situer dans le passé.

EDIT : Oui, on peut tout aussi bien tourner la phrase comme tu le suggères avec un passé composé. C'est très correct aussi mais la valeur n'est pas la même.
Utiliser un futur antérieur peut permettre de traduire la supposition ou diverses nuances d'indignation, d'agacement ou d'ironie.

Ainsi... "*Cela t'en aura pris un temps pour faire ce travail !*" (Sous entendu moqueur)
"*J’aurai fait ce travail bien inutilement !*" (Agacement sous-entendu)

Avec donc :"ça aura pris du temps mais je réalise que mon père était un grand homme", le locuteur se moque un peu de lui même. (De n'avoir pas réalisé la chose plus vite)